# differences of ''and'', ''or'' in the questions

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Prove or disprove in the below questions:

$1.$ Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Then $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3$ implies $a=0$ **OR** $b=0$.

Disproof. Let $a=-1$ and $b=1$. Then, we also get $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3=0$.

$2.$ Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Then $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3$ implies $a=0$ **AND** $b=0$.

Disproof. Let $a=-1$ and $b=1$. Then, we also get $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3=0$.

Can you say what is the difference between question-1 and question-2?
 And can you check my proofs?

Comment: A disproof is what?

Comment: @Wuestenfux it means counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in that specific example the answers are the same. Still, these are two different questions. For example $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$ but it doesn't imply that **both** must be zeros.

And yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: My answer works for two questions, right? I don't sure.

Comment: Yes. In that specific exercise the same counterexample works for both questions.

Comment: Thanks for answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

We have $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3 \iff 3a^2b+3ab^2=0 \iff ab(a+b)=0 \iff a=0$ or $b=0$ or $a=-b$.

Answer (score 0):

Your two disproofs are correct. To clarfy difference, for example if you could have said like this (and suppose it is true for $x\neq 0$,  I know it is not true but just suppose)

Disproof: Let $a=x$, $b=0$ then we get $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3=0$

Then the disproof would have worked  for question 2, but not 1

Answer (score 0):

The selected counterexample disproves both claims.   Yet not all counterexamples will disprove both claims.

To demonstrate the difference between the claims consider this:

> Disproof: Let $a=0$ **or** $b=0$, but not both, then we have $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3$

This counterexample disproves the claim that the equality implies $a=0$ **and** $b=0$.

However, it clearly does *not* disprove the claim that the equality implies $a=0$ **or** $b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution of the equation is:
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3 \iff \{(a,b)\in R^2|a=0 \ \text{or} \ b=0 \ \text{or} \ a=-b\}.$$
And note:
$$\begin{align}A&=\{(a,b)\in R^2|a=0 \ \text{and} \ b=0\};\\
B&=\{(a,b)\in R^2|a=0 \ \text{or} \ b=0\}; \\
C&=\{(a,b)\in R^2|a=0 \ \text{or} \ b=0 \ \text{or} \ a=-b\};\\
A& \subset B \subset C.\end{align}$$
You can disprove the elements of the smaller set by taking the elements of the bigger set.
For example:
$$(a,b)=(0,5)\notin A; (a,b)=(0,5)\in B \Rightarrow (0+5)^3=0^3+5^3 \ \ \checkmark \\
(a,b)=(1,-1)\notin B; (a,b)=(1,-1)\in C \Rightarrow (1-1)^3=1^3+(-1)^3 \ \ \checkmark \\$$